# Original sanskrit e-book of 'Tripura Rahasya'

Tags: scripture, philosophy, translation-request, sanskrit, tripura-rahasyam

Can someone post me a free downloadable link to the original Sanskrit e-book of 'Tripura Rahasya'?

I have the English translation given by Wikipedia. But I was in need of the Sanskrit version.

Could anyone help me in this regard? I would appreciate any help forwarded.

Answer (score 7):

Tripura Rahasya (Sanskrit) Mahatmya Kanda can be found [here](https://www.scribd.com/document/28966805/Tripura-Rahasya-Mahatmya-Khanda-Sanskrit-Text) and Jnana Kanda can be found [here](https://www.scribd.com/document/28968187/Tripura-Rahasya-Jnana-Khanda-Sanskrit-Text).

Answer (score 4):

According to the [introduction](https://scriptures.ru/tripura1.htm#INTRODUCTION) of the book Tripura Rahasya,  the book has three kandas: The Maahaatmya Khanda (6,687), Jnaana Khanda (2,163) and Charyaa Khanda (3150?).

> The work was thus written by Haritaayana and is also called after his
> name Haritaayana Samhita. It is said to consist of 12,000 slokaas in
> three sections — The Maahaatmya Khanda (Section on the Greatness of
> Srii Deevi), Jnaana Khanda (Section on Supreme Wisdom), and Charyaa
> Khanda (Section on Conduct). Of these the first consists of 6,687
> slokaas; the second of 2,163 slokaas; **and the third is not traceable.**
> The section on Greatness contains the prelude to the work and later
> treats mostly of the manifestations of the Supreme Being as Durga,
> Kaali, Lakshmi, Sarasvati, Lalita, Kumaari, etc. and their exploits
> and found in Brahmaanda Puraana, Maarkandeya Puraana and Lakshmi
> Tantra. Its contents mostly cover the ground of Durga Saptasati and of
> Lalita Upaakhaayana.

The first two khandas, Maahaatmya and Jnaana are available, in Sanskrit, in the archive. I think the third one is also available, but I am not sure about it.

[Maahaatmya Khanda](https://archive.org/details/TripurarahasyaMahatmyaKhandaMukundLalShastri),

[Jnaana Khanda](https://archive.org/details/TripuraRahasyamJnanaKhandaGopinathKaviraj/mode/1up) and

[Charyaa Khanda](https://archive.org/details/ChikitusiIITripuraRahasyaCharyaKhandWagishShukla/mode/1up)

The introduction clearly says that Charyaa Khanda is intractable. So, I am unsure about the source of Charyaa khanda and cannot verify the authenticity as I am not well aware of Sanskrit.

Comment: The main intention in posting this answer is that the links in the other answer are not active. And to give some more information.